# Single word which refers to restaurants, bars and clubs?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need a word that refers to restaurants, bars and clubs. Places where you usually talk with friends, go on dates, or dance. I thought about "Spots" or "Places" but I'm not sure if people will associate them with travel.

Comment: It wasn't me, but perhaps because it can be answered with a web search for synonyms.

Comment: @Hugo I'm not looking for synonyms but for a category/word which includes many others (word choice).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One word you can use is [*venue*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/venue):

> the scene or locale of any action or event.

You often hear this word in the context of concerts, but it is any location where something could take place. Another option is [*hotspot*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hotspot), which refers to nightclubs and the like.

Comment: I reckon *venue* is the most appropriate word here.

Comment: __Venue__ is more a term for performers, that is, it tells a performer that such a place is one where they can perform. And even then, to call a restaurant that has live music, it is a venue only for the performers, not for the people looking for something to eat _or_ be entertained.

Comment: "Venue" is just so broad, it could be referring to a public park or library, really anything. It's not limited to performances either, unless I am mistaken, but usually refers to the place an event is being held (could be a bake sale or meeting, anything).

Answer (score 6):

Some suitable synonyms from a simple web search: **hangout, joint, watering hole, nightspot, pub, dive, drinkery, venue**.

Comment: Wow, thanks but now I have so many options. I don't know what to choose.

Comment: Well, what's your context?

Comment: I'm building a forum for foreigners in Taiwan. I want a topics category for places were people can eat, drink, chat, and socialize (in other words, drinking and non-drinking places).

Comment: I think "venue" is the best gerneral-purpose term for your needs, given your explanation.

Comment: *Nightspot* and *hangout* seem to capture what you’re after much more specifically than the other suggestions.  *Venue*, for instance, suggests a place that you hear/see performances, so it can also cover concert halls/arenas, and depending on context people might not expect it to include restaurants.

Answer (score 3):

You may use ***hangout***.

> a favorite place for spending time; also : a place frequented for
>   entertainment or for socializing.

Comment: *Hangout* is, in my opinion, an americanism. It would sound contrived if used here in Australia.

Answer (score 2):

> [Horeca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horeca) is a business term which refers to a sector of the food
>   service industry, to establishments which prepare and serve food and
>   beverages. The term is a syllabic abbreviation of the words
>   Hotel/Restaurant/Café.

it hails from Dutch and may be a bit obscure

Comment: I'm not sure most users would recognize what that is. It also sounds like it would be pronounced like a certain pejorative term for women.

Comment: I sounds like the combination of a pejorative term for women which starts with w and eureka.

Comment: We use this all the time in Dutch. We will conquer the world and teach it to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

A "catchall" term in this regard is "night life."

Answer (score 1):

Because the concept encompasses two things considered distinct, I don't think there is a single term for it. From my memory of such listings in newspapers and magazines, one is *dining* and the other is *entertainment* or possibly *nightlife*. I would label this concept:

**Dining and Entertainment**

Comment: Something like this seems most appropriate judging by OP's comment on another answer: "I'm building a forum for foreigners in Taiwan. I want a topics category for places were people can eat, drink, chat, and socialize (in other words, drinking and non-drinking places)."

Answer (score 1):

If you want something all encompassing perhaps referring to them as **Establishments** may work.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with "restaurants, bars and clubs"? It's better than most of the single word answers given above. Nightlife is a great answer, but refers to the activity rather than the location.