# One word for nightclub and bar

Tags: word-usage

Would you use `bar` to describe both or is there a better word? The distinction is often that a nightclub has a dance floor and a bar doesn't.

Looking up the synonyms I got `disco`, `club`, `joint` and `pub`. I don't think either of them are good enough to describe both.

Comment: Have you looked up synonyms for these words?

Comment: @Davo Yes. I got disco, club, joint and pub. I dont think either of them are good enough do describe both. Am I wrong?

Comment: That information should be edited into your question.

Comment: @Davo It's done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single word which refers to restaurants, bars and clubs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/single-word-which-refers-to-restaurants-bars-and-clubs)

Comment: Another problem is that *bar* can also mean the specific area behind which a bartender stands in order to serve drinks. So, an establishment both *contain* a bar as well as *be* a bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you a hypernym for **bar** and **nightclub**: they're both **[drinking establishments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Types_of_drinking_establishment)**.

It's not one word though, it's two. And it's not snappy and informal.

---

I'm not sure on the use of **bar** for both **bar** and **nightclub**. I (as a native British English speaker) don't tend to use the word **bar** much at all, I tend (or rather, tended) to go either a **pub** or a **club**. A **bar** is something I found when I went on holiday to Europe.

As you say, somewhere with a proper dancefloor isn't a bar, it's a club. People do make a distinction between a bar and a club, see e.g. the lyrics to Shape of You by Ed Sheeran:

> A club isn't the best place to find a lover, so the bar is where I go

All that said, the wikipedia page for [bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar) says:

> A bar (also known as a saloon or a tavern or sometimes as a pub or club

and the page for club says:

> A nightclub, music club or club, is an entertainment venue and bar that usually operates late into the night

So clearly some people do think that a club is a type of bar, so using **bar** for both would be acceptable.

Comment: Would you think that "nightspot" is good enough? I am a programmer and right now trying to find a word for both because I am forced to. I think "nightspot" shall work.

Comment: Never heard of a "nightspot" before. Googling it, it seems to only apply to nightclubs. "Nightlife venue" maybe? But again that's two words.